# Emulator infinite errors shown in Console [Android]

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am new to Android and my team is currently developing a game. The game includes AndEngine library. I am running it in Eclipse Indigo. My AVD has a GPU emulation. When I run our project, the emulator appears but on the screen, it's all white. When I look at the console, I see infinite errors and it stops when I close the Emulator. Help please!

```
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] ------------------------------
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] Android Launch!
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] Performing com.example.zombieannihilation_ar.Zombie_Annihilation activity launch
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Zombie' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-09-21 22:30:45 - zombieannihilation_AR] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Zombie'
[2012-09-21 22:31:03 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 512MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 384MB.
[2012-09-21 22:31:09 - Emulator] creating window 28 27 240 400
[2012-09-21 22:31:09 - zombieannihilation_AR] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-09-21 22:31:09 - zombieannihilation_AR] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:21 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:25 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:33 - zombieannihilation_AR] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.zombieannihilation_ar.Zombie_Annihilation activity launch'!
[2012-09-21 22:32:33 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glGenFramebuffersOES:1938 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2DOES:1958 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glCheckFramebufferStatusOES:1951 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glBindFramebufferOES:1913 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp:glDeleteFramebuffersOES:1929 error 0x502
[2012-09-21 22:32:35 - Emulator] Error accepting connection, aborting
```

those are some of the errors. i need your help, i badly need to run our project. THANK YOU!

Comment: Same here, when "GPU emulation" enabled. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the chosen emulator does not support GLES ? 0x502 = GL_INVALID_OPERATION.
Sure you have correct emulator ? -> Preferred AVD 'Zombie' is not available.

Comment: that AVD is available.

TARGET: Google APIs 15; 
SD card:128 Mb; 
Skin Built-in: WQVGA400; 
Abstracted lcd density: 120; 
max vm application heap size: 48; 
device ram size: 512; 
GPU emulation: yes